# Chrome printing bug - wrongly printing table headers at top of page

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

(Addendum: This is [Chrome issue 631222](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=631222), and was fixed in Chrome release 54.0.*.)

With the latest version (53.0.2785.116) of Chrome, on Windows and Mac, we've hit a nasty bug that we can't seem to work around.

We are seeking workarounds that do not involve editing the HTML text, so CSS or Javascript answers might do.

We are getting text at the top of pages other than the first that looks like:

[image]

This is an overlay of a paragraph, and two different table headers for tables that occur later on that page. (Where the headers again are printed.)

You can find a full [example page here.](http://thomasoandrews.com/examples/ChromePrintBug.html)

We've already reported this to Google, of course, but we were wondering if anybody could think of a workaround to get our customers printing again. We can't change the HTML, but we can change the CSS, or possibly use Javascript. (Removing the thead tags appears to solve the problem, for example, but that solution does not work for us because we can't change the HTML.)

The code is simply:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<title>Broken Printing</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Printing Issue 9/29/2016</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum for page break</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<table> 
    <thead><tr><th>Survey</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody><tr class="odd"><td>The Foundation 2016&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody>
</table>

<table>
    <thead><tr><th>Year</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody><tr><td>2015</td></tr></tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We now have a partial workaround - setting the thead display CSS to 'table-row-group'. Imperfect if any table splits across pages, but that is rare in our case.

Comment: @MrLister Yeah, not sure why validators are getting 403 errors. When I paste the contents of the URL into the validator, it works fine. Not sure what is up with the 403 on my site - I see w3c requests in the logs, with the 403 response. I don't seen anything in my .htaccess which would cause that.

Comment: And it's not just this page, it's your whole site. Anyway, apart from that, there's nothing wrong with your page. I think it's a bug in Chrome. Is changing the thead to another tbody an option? That would only require a small and straightforward bit of JavaScript.

Comment: @MrLister Yeah, I think it is something configured on my provider's side - I used to use the W3C validator all the time on my site.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We have a workaround:

```
@media  print {
    thead { 
        display: table-row-group 
    }
}
```

This loses a feature we don't need much in our reports - repeating of table headers at page breaks - so it is sufficient for us, and is easily removed when Chrome gets fixed.

Comment: Here in 2022, Chrome still has not fixed the issue.

Comment: Well, if it has reverted, it reverted recently. We aren't seeing it again at my work. @antman

Comment: I did some more testing, and you're right. My issue turns out to be a slightly different issue where my table (and some other content) is wrapped in a big flex box, and the rows overflow to another page. Your work-around worked for my situation as well. I'll report my issue separately to Chrome. Thanks.